# CMake имя библиотеки

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

В `Android studio` собираю so библиотеки через `CMake`.

`CMakeList.txt`

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         test

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/ccp/test.c )

         target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   test

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

После компиляции приложения в папке lib вижу(через архиватор) `testlib.so`.Как сделать имя `test.so` автоматом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В CMake Вы можете указать нужный вам суфикс и префикс
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html

```
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Comment: Как раз тут сидел и вкуривал

Comment: теперь по 2 либы создается видимо target_link_libraries не нужно использовать

Comment: создает testlib и просто test.Как исправить?

Comment: clean проекта не помогает? Предположу что возможно от старых настроек осталось.